# startx function/alias has wrong arguments if not prefixed with exec

Tags: bash, shell-script, x11, function, startx

For context, my file/directory structure and contents are mostly copied from how it is in Luke Smith's dotfiles ([voidrice](https://github.com/LukeSmithxyz/voidrice/)). Also, the "..." lines in the code blocks aren't code and represent omitted lines in the file.

I have this in my `~/.zprofile`:

```bash
#!/bin/zsh
...
export XINITRC="${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}/x11/xinitrc"
```

And this in my aliases file that `~/.zshrc` sources (`~/.config/shell/aliasrc`):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
...
esx() { exec startx "$XINITRC" "$@" -- -keeptty >~/xorg.log 2>&1; }
sx() { startx "$XINITRC" "$@" -- -keeptty >~/xorg.log 2>&1; }
```

(The "--" part of the functions' commands onwards is for [logging](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xorg#Session_log_redirection))

This is what `~/.config/x11/xinitrc` looks like:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
sysresources="/etc/X11/xinit/.Xresources"
userXprofile="${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}/x11/xprofile" # empty file atm
[ -f "$sysresources" ] && xrdb -merge "$sysresources"
xrdb -merge ${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}/x11/xresources & xrdbpid=$!
if [ -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d ] ; then
 for f in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/?*.sh ; do
  [ -x "$f" ] && . "$f"
 done
 unset f
fi
if [ -f "$userXprofile" ]; then
    . "$userXprofile"
else
    . "$HOME/.xprofile"
fi
[ -n "$xrdbpid" ] && wait "$xrdbpid"
case $1 in
   awesome|awesomeWM) exec awesome;;
   xfce|xfce4) exec startxfce4;;
   openbox) exec openbox;;
esac
```

Basically, the intention is to run either `esx` or `sx` with the name of whatever window manager or desktop environment I want to use for that particular session. It works properly with `esx`, but `sx` will pass the value of $XINITRC to `~/.config/x11/xinitrc` as $1 instead of the WM/DE I picked. I tried "fixing" `sx` by excluding the first argument:

`sx() { startx "$XINITRC" "${@:2}" -- -keeptty >~/xorg.log 2>&1; }`

but xinitrc still has $1 as $XINITRC. As a band-aid fix, `~/.config/x11/xinitrc` gets rid of the first positional argument if it's "$XINITRC":

```bash
[ "$1" = "$XINITRC" ] && shift
case $1 in
...
```

But I hate this solution and would much rather know why `sx` is screwing up in the first place. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: I think this question could be reduced to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), as it looks like it is about `exec` and possibly zsh/Bash, rather than X.Org. `startx` is itself usually a shell script, and can be debugged as any other shell script.

Comment: Actually, this could more likely be related to the `startx` script itself, so try debugging it first.